# Properties of unicorn blood

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

What are the properties of unicorn blood in D&D 5e? I can't find anything in the DMG, PHB or Monster Manual.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think it *has* properties?

Comment: @Miniman Too much Harry Potter, I reckon.

Comment: 1) Red and sticky. 2) Hard to wash out. 3) Spurts from stabbed unicorns.

Comment: @Miniman My DM gave me some when I had an encounter with a unicorn and received my animal companion. My character just died and I am facepalming because I might not have died if anyone had remembered that. I also wanted to check and make sure it didn't have resurrection properties to save my companions a thousand gold on the spell.

Comment: @LordPride Thanks, that makes sense. I'll ask my DM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 5th edition it is the Unicorns horns that have magical properties in a fluff sense. Unicorn blood is not mentioned, however there is no reason why a DM couldn't assign a property if they so wished. However again, there is no RAW ruling on the matter.